# Как правильно в Laravel подключить шриф Raleway с кириллицей

Tags: laravel, шрифты

В Laravel 5.3, по-умолчанию идет шрифт "Raleway", который грузится с Google Fonts, но в нем (в том, который хостится на гуглу), похоже, нет кириллических символов.

Кто-нибудь задавался вопросом подключения этого шрифта с кириллицей? Как нынче считается правильно загружать шрифты на веб-страницах? И где взять именно этот шрифт.

Answer (score 1):

На Google Fonts нет кириллицы на сколько я знаю. Скачать можно [тут](http://fonts4web.ru/download.html?font=Raleway) к примеру.
Потом устанавливаем шрифт в CSS:

1. Для того, чтобы установить шрифт Raleway в свой HTML-проект, сперва скопируйте содержимое архива в папку /fonts, которая должна лежать в той-же директории, что и папка /css вашего HTML сайта.

   Структура проекта после установки шрифтов:
   / (корневой каталог шаблона или проекта)

   ```
   /fonts (Шрифты из архива распаковываем в папку /fonts)
       /RalewayRegular
       /RalewayThin
       /RalewayExtraLight
       /RalewayLight
       /RalewayMedium
       /RalewaySemiBold
       /RalewayBold
       /RalewayExtraBold
       /RalewayBlack

   /css (Папка со стилями должна находиться в той-же категории, что и /fonts)
       /stylename.css (Файл стилей, в котором подключаются русские шрифты)
   ```
2. Далее вставляем код, указанный ниже, в файл стилей, который должен находиться в папке /css.

> ```
> /* Код для подключения шрифта в /css/stylename.css */
>
> /* font-family: "RalewayRegular"; */
>
> @font-face {
>     font-family: "RalewayRegular";
>     src: url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.eot");
>     src: url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
>     url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.woff") format("woff"),
>     url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.ttf") format("truetype");
>     font-style: normal;
>     font-weight: normal;
> }
> ```

Теперь подключаете CSS на страницу и пользуйтесь. 
Больше примеров можете найти по ссылке: http://fonts4web.ru/raleway.html

Comment: Спасибо за инфу. Imho, как-то это все "в обход" встроенной системы управления ресурсами в виде gulp+elixir, а это очень интересная тема сама по себе. Вот пример подключения шрифтов из bootstrap, например: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795847/glyphicons-not-showing-with-sass-bootstrap-integration